# Add Number of accepted answer of a user @ IMPACT box

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I think accepted answer is very important point to be considered. It is major IMPACT of user I think. It also responsible for %Answer of site.

[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work):

> Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters **for solving your problem** and informs others that your issue is resolved.

So, I think Number of accepted answers of a user (may be excluding self answer) should be considered at IMPACT box.

Note: I am **not** talking about featuring number of accepted answer by user **but** I am talking about number of answers of users that are accepted.

Comment: No please don't. There used to be something called "accept rate" that appeared along with reputation and badges in user cards, and caused more harm than good.

Comment: Are you suggesting displaying the number of answers a user has accepted or the number of answers a user has written that were accepted by the asker?

Comment: @AlE. Second one.

Comment: Probably want to [edit] your question to clarify, then.

Comment: @AlE. edited and welcome to provide better title

Comment: Try `\` hello hello

Answer (score 2):

In either way, I disagree adding this to the box.

The current *X people reached* takes into account two things: the number of questions/answers and their views. I can answer a dozen questions, but if those questions aren't helpful to the community, they don't add to your impact, since that answer didn't have any impact. If someone else accepts your answer, what did you gain? Maybe you have a history of being second (just behind Jon Skeets answer). Does that mean your answer was less valuable? I think not.

Also, if it is about the accept rate of the user: no, we don't want that too. It was [removed for very good reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/245360) and we don't want it back.